# Descargar archivos pdf Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Hola amigos estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación en `Django`para descarga archivos en `pdf`, pero tengo una gran duda, ojala puedan apoyarme.

Cuando hago voy a una `URL` esto lo hago con el método `GET`,

Usando el ejemplo que está en la documentación de `Django` para descargar archivos funciona perfecto, pero que pasaría si en lugar de ir a `URL` lo quiero hacer por medio de `Ajax` y `post` para descargar un archivo?

¿Es esto posible?

```
Response[“content-disposition”]
```

Funciona bien es solo que cuando a esa vista le puse un

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

Simplemente no descarga el archivo, si lo hago mediante `jquery` + `ajax`.

Ojala alguien pueda aclararme esta duda.

O quizá es que tengo que crear una sola vista únicamente para descargar archivos.

Saludos.

Comment: agrega codigo para ver todo el request ,

Answer (score 1):

Lo que debes hacer es vía `ajax` retornar la `URL` donde esta ubicado tu archivo generado es decir previamente debes guardarlo, una ruta como esta:

```
media/reportes/miReporte.pdf
```

Entonces sabemos que siempre se guardara mi `pdf` allí, por lo cual nos resta abrir dicha `URL` en una ventana emergente:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/reports/",
  data : { 
    'fecInicio' : $("#fecInicio").val() , 
    'fecFin' : $("#fecFin").val() 
  },
  success : function(result){
     var url = result.url;
     window.location = url;
  },
```

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!